# load data local infile imports only 200k out of 400k records

Tags: mysql, database, csv

**Hello! I am new to MYSQL so kindly explain in as simple language as possible!**

I have a csv with 400k rows and want to import it into mysql. I am using **LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE** command for this purpose:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/Comorbidity Covid-19.csv'
INTO TABLE `comorbidity covid-19`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

The issue is that **only about 200k records are being imported while the csv contains 400k records**. Why is this happening? I executed the command both in the **command prompt** and in **MySql Workbench** but both give the same output. Also the **date column is not being imported correctly**. Instead of dates being displayed it is showing **0000-00-00** in each rows.

**PS:** OPT_LOCAL_INFILE=1 in manage database connections!

**PS : Here is some sample data**

[image]

What I did was first I created an empty table in the database with respective column types by. I created an empty table with only the column headers by right clicking on tables and selecting create new table option where I selected the proper type for each columns.. `Date as of` and `Start Date` were given Date type and so on. Then I executed the above query both in command prompt and workbench to import the rows.

**show create table comorbidity gives this result:**

```
CREATE TABLE `comorbidity` (
  `Date as of` date NOT NULL,
  `Start Date` date NOT NULL,
  `State` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Condition group` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Condition` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Age group` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `Covid19 deaths` int NOT NULL,
  `Number of mentions` int NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Comment: `comorbidity covid-19` this is really a **bad table name** . Post table description and some data of the  `Comorbidity Covid-19.csv` file you are importing

Comment: @ErgestBasha Added relevant details. I also tried using a different name but no luck!

Comment: and the table description? First column is not a valid date format

Comment: 1.) Table description as in? I am not able to get what you mean by that.  2.) What is the correct date format then? When creating the empty table, I selected DATE as the type for the first 2 columns.

Comment: run  **show create table `comorbidity covid-19`** . In your csv file date is in `02-06-2022` format. The correct format shuld be `2022-06-02` `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: Added the description. So you mean to say Mysql only supports `yyyy-mm-dd` format and no other format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason only 200k records were being imported was because I was using:

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

When I changed it to:

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

All 400 k records were imported.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the date is not in the correct format that is why it looks wrong. Try to modify the field from excel to a correct format, or perform a DATE() function for the date.

On the subject of importing all the records, check if there is any character that interrupts the execution.

Comment: Hi! I am new to mysql so can you kindly explain simply? When creating the table I selected the proper types for all columns. So for date columns I had selected DATE type, text columns as VARCHAR and numerical as INT.

Comment: Change the dates to the format "Y-m-d H:i:s".
Example: 01-01-2020 to 2020-01-01 00:00:00

Comment: So you mean to say Mysql only supports one kind of date format that is `yyyy-mm-dd`?

Comment: DATE is with this format. But you can change the inputs and the outputs.

Comment: How do I do it then?

Comment: Change the values of the csv first. Or create a table with this column as varchar and then with a trigger update the value to the column with the correct format